# Multiple file version checks on multiple computers

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a Powershell script that does the following:
1) reads the list of files from a txt file. The txt file will contain the path and name of the file, for example: \Program Files (x86)\AppName\application.exe
after reading the list of files, Powershell then reads from another txt file and imports a list of computers, for example

```
pc-001
pc-002
pc-003
...
```

After checking each computer for the file versions, it then outputs the data to a txt file in the following format:

```
PC-001
\Program Files (x86)\AppName\application.exe - version details
\Program Files (x86)\AppName\anotherfile.dll - version details

PC-002
\Program Files (x86)\AppName\application.exe - version details
\Program Files (x86)\AppName\anotherfile.dll - version details

PC-002
\Program Files (x86)\AppName\application.exe - version details
\Program Files (x86)\AppName\anotherfile.dll - version details
```

So far, I have come up with this:

```psh
$filename = "\Program Files (x86)\application\application.exe" 

$obj = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList 

$computernames = Get-Content C:\Computer.csv 
foreach ($server in $computernames) { 
  $filepath = Test-Path "\\$server\c$\$filename" 

  if ($filepath -eq "True") { 
    $file = Get-Item "\\$server\c$\$filename" 

    $obj += New-Object psObject -Property @{
              'Computer'       = $server;
              'FileVersion'    = $file.VersionInfo|Select FileVersion;
              'LastAccessTime' = $file.LastWriteTime
            } 
  } 
} 

$obj | select computer, FileVersion, lastaccesstime |
  Export-Csv -Path 'c:\File_Results.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Does anyone know how I could modify the file to get the information I need in the format listed above?

Comment: Your desired output format says "version details", but your code selects file version and last write time (mis-labeled "last access time"). Please clarify what your output should contain.

Answer (score 0):

You should use double dot qualifier to get nested field of a  `FileVersionInfo` object into your `$obj`, like this:

```
$obj += New-Object psObject -Property @{'Computer'=$server;'FileVersion'=$file.VersionInfo.FileVersion;'LastAccessTime'=$file.LastWriteTime}
```

Also, while you don't have more fields in your `New-Object` objects, the intermittent `select` in the last line of your script is not needed.